# TypeError: Function_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a sript.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()

class btn_maker:
    def __init__(self,window,cmd,row=0,column=0):
        self = Button(window,command=cmd)
        self.grid(row=row,column=column)
    def XorO(self):
        self.config(text = 'X')

btn1 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=0,column=0)
btn2 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=0,column=1)
btn3 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=0,column=2)
btn4 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=1,column=0)
btn5 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=1,column=1)
btn6 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=1,column=2)
btn7= btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=2,column=0)
btn8= btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=2,column=1)
btn9 = btn_maker(window,btn_maker.XorO,row=2,column=2)


window.mainloop()
```

It gives an error TypeError: Function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I need that XorO function changes text of button
How can I do that ?

Comment: Assigning to `self` inside your `__init__` method is not useful. I'm not sure what you were trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an unbound method as the `cmd` argument, so you have to pass the `btn_maker` instance when calling `cmd`. You can do this with `lambda`.

```
class btn_maker:
    def __init__(self,window,cmd,row=0,column=0):
        self.btn = Button(window,command=lambda: cmd(self))
        self.btn.grid(row=row,column=column)
    def XorO(self):
        self.btn.config(text = 'X')
```

You also shouldn't reassign the `self` variable, use a different variable internally within the method. And in this case you should use an instance attribute so that you can access the button in the other method.

Comment: I think OP expects `btn_maker` to return a `Button` instance. While this answer is correct, I am not sure it will be completely useful for OP.

Comment: In that case `btn_maker()` should be an ordinary function, not a class.

Comment: Why don't `btn_maker` inherit from `Button` instead? Base on OP code, the `cmd` option is not necessary.

Comment: That may be a possibility. But then its `__init__()` method needs to be able to take all the parameters of `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work as you think it does.
When in `__init__` you are reassigning `self`, that does not mean that `btn1` contains a variable of type `Button`.
You are confusing the `__init__` and `__new__` methods.
But probably writing a `__new__` method that returns an instance of `Button` or any other inheritance is unnecessarily complicating the code.

A class is probably not the best option for your case. If, for whatever reason, you want to keep it, this is a possible way to do it:

```
from functools import partial

class btn_maker:
    # We don't provide init method.
    # We use this class to encapsulate code, we don't need its instances

    @classmethod
    def make(cls, window, cmd=None, row=0, column=0) -> Button:
        # If the user doesn't provide other cmd, XorO will be used
        cmd = cmd or cls.XorO

        # Create a StringVar to change button content
        btn_text = StringVar()
        # Create a function that modifies our StringVar
        cmd = partial(cls.XorO, btn_text)
        # Create the instance we will return. Set the text and the command
        btn = Button(window,command=cmd,textvariable=btn_text)
        # Set the position
        btn.grid(row=row,column=column)

        # Return the new Button instance
        return btn

    @staticmethod
    def XorO(btn_text: StringVar):
        # Static method because it does not need btn_maker, it just manipulates the button
        btn_text.set('X')

btn1 = btn_maker.make(window, row=0, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to overwrite `self` inside `__init__()` and I think what you need is to inherit `btn_maker` from `ttk.Button` instead:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class btn_maker(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, window, row=0, column=0):
        super().__init__(window, command=self.XorO)
        self.grid(row=row, column=column)

    def XorO(self):
        self.config(text='X')

window = tk.Tk()

btn1 = btn_maker(window, row=0, column=0)
btn2 = btn_maker(window, row=0, column=1)
btn3 = btn_maker(window, row=0, column=2)
btn4 = btn_maker(window, row=1, column=0)
btn5 = btn_maker(window, row=1, column=1)
btn6 = btn_maker(window, row=1, column=2)
btn7 = btn_maker(window, row=2, column=0)
btn8 = btn_maker(window, row=2, column=1)
btn9 = btn_maker(window, row=2, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Note also that wildcard import is not recommended.